# Multidimensional list to pair similar data by time

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Figure A** - Data given in .txt file

**Figure B** - My attempt to solve it. What I have been able to accomplish so far is checking the .txt and storing the appropriate records into different list. My goal is to pair each record to the time It was run/completed and transfer it into an Access database. I'm thinking about maybe taking a multidimensional list approach but completely lost on where to begin.

```
program1 STARTED AT 2017-06-07-14.31.34.827086
REC READ     =   265
REC WRITTEN  =   265
CALLS        =     82
SHPR FOUND   =     69
SHPR NOT FND =         3
ADDR FOUND   =     3169
ADDR NOT FND =           0
INELIG SYS   =           7
ELIG   SYS   =     3762
program1 COMPLETED AT 2017-06-07-14.35.56.067879
=========================================================
program1 STARTED AT 2017-06-07-14.31.34.827086
REC READ     =   165
REC WRITTEN  =   235
CALLS        =     32
SHPR FOUND   =     649
SHPR NOT FND =         23
ADDR FOUND   =     31369
ADDR NOT FND =           10
INELIG SYS   =           471
ELIG   SYS   =     762
program1 COMPLETED AT 2017-06-07-14.35.56.067879
```

My current code below (Figure B)

```
file = open(r"C:\Users\Desktop\joblogs.txt", "r")

rec_read = []
rec_written = []
calls = []
shpr_found = []
shpr_nf = []
addr_found = []
addr_nf = []
inelig_sys = []
elig_sys = []

for line in file:
   line = line.strip()
   if "REC READ" in line:
       line = (line.split()[-1])
       rec_read.append(line)
   if "REC WRITTEN" in line:
       line = (line.split()[-1])
       rec_written.append(line)
   if "CC01 CALLS" in line:
       line = (line.split()[-1])
       calls.append(line)
   if "SHPR FOUND" in line:
       line = (line.split()[-1])
       shpr_found.append(line)
   if "SHPR NOT FND" in line:
       line = (line.split()[-1])
       shpr_nf.append(line)
   if "ADDR FOUND" in line:
       line = (line.split()[-1])
       addr_found.append(line)
   if "ADDR NOT FND" in line:
       line = (line.split()[-1])
       addr_nf.append(line)
   if "INELIG SYS" in line:
       line = (line.split()[-1])
       inelig_sys.append(line)
   if "ELIG   SYS" in line:
       line = (line.split()[-1])
       elig_sys.append(line)


print(rec_read)
print(rec_written)
print(calls)
print(shpr_found)
print(shpr_nf)
print(addr_found)
print(addr_nf)
print(inelig_sys)
print(elig_sys)
```

Comment: How about a dictionary? Check out this link [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with dictionaries:

```
d = {}
count = 0

for line in file:
    if '==' in line:
        continue

    if 'STARTED' in line:
        start_time = line.split(' ')[-1]
        d[count] = {'start_time': start_time}
        continue

    if 'COMPLETED' in line:
        end_time = line.split(' ')[-1]
        d[count].update({'end_time': end_time})
        count += 1
        continue

    x, y = line.split('=')

    x = x.strip()
    y = y.strip()

    d[count].update({x:y})
```

Result:

```
{0: {'ADDR FOUND': '3169',
     'ADDR NOT FND': '0',
     'CALLS': '82',
     'ELIG   SYS': '3762',
     'INELIG SYS': '7',
     'REC READ': '265',
     'REC WRITTEN': '265',
     'SHPR FOUND': '69',
     'SHPR NOT FND': '3',
     'end_time': '2017-06-07-14.35.56.067879',
     'start_time': '2017-06-07-14.31.34.827086'},
 1: {'ADDR FOUND': '31369',
     'ADDR NOT FND': '10',
     'CALLS': '32',
     'ELIG   SYS': '762',
     'INELIG SYS': '471',
     'REC READ': '165',
     'REC WRITTEN': '235',
     'SHPR FOUND': '649',
     'SHPR NOT FND': '23',
     'end_time': '2017-06-07-14.35.56.067879',
     'start_time': '2017-06-07-14.31.34.827086'}}
```

Comment: Is this a standalone code or i should incorporate it with mine?

Comment: I made a change to the code. You can incorporate it into yours.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of exactly how I will incorporate this into my current code.

Comment: I attempted to use your code by pasting it in and see the result I get. Nothing happens. Not even your results

Comment: File "C:/Users/cqt7wny/PycharmProjects/testapp/read.py", line 27, in <module>
    x, y = line.split('=')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: What was the text it was trying to parse that resulted in the error? You could put a print statement before it. `print line`